# Abelian subgroup of standard wreath product

Tags: group-theory, wreath-product

Let $A$ and $B$ be non-trivial groups. We construct their (restricted) wreath product as follows.
 Denote by $A^{(B)}$ the set of all function from $B$ to $A$ with finite support, and equip it with pointwise multiplication to make it a group. The wreath product $A\wr B$ is the semidirect product $A^{(B)}\ltimes B$. Therefore the elements of $A\wr B$ are pairs $(f,b)$ where $f\in A^{(B)}$ and $b\in B$. Multiplication in $A\wr B$  is given by
 $$(f,b)(g,c)=(fg^b,bc)$$
 where $g^b(x)=g(b^{-1}x)$ for every $x\in B$.

Now let $A$ and $B$ be finitely generated free abelian group and $W=A\wr B$. Is this true that every non-cyclic abelian subgroup is contained in $A^{(B)}$ or a conjugate of $B$?

Comment: Well no, it could be contained in a conjugate of $B$, so perhaps you want to modify the question.

Comment: I tried some quick calculations but I could not resolve it. What is the source of this problem? Is it an exercise or is something that has arisen in some other context?

Comment: No it is not an exercise. I need to know what is the structure of abelian subgroups of this wreath product. I think a abelian subgroup of this wreath product is contained in $A^{(B)}$ or it is isomorphic to a subgroup of $B$

Comment: That's an easier question! It is not hard to show that the centralizer in $A^B$ of every element of $W$ outside of $A^B$ is trivial. So an abelian subgroup of $W$ is either contained in $A^B$, or it has trivial intersection with $A^B$, in which case it is isomorphic to a subgroup of $W/A^B \cong B$.